# Disable default Polymer CSS

Tags: javascript, css, html, polymer, web-component

I built an application using Polymer and its working as intended. I'd like to style it with a totally custom look and feel.

Is it possible to disable default styling of Polymer elements via a flag or some roundabout way, or will I have to manually override everything I want to change?

Comment: Can you post a jsbin of what you're trying to achieve. Example code is helpful :) It's not clear what you mean by "default Polymer css". CSS of the `<polymer-*>` elements, elements you create,...?

Comment: I am trying to change the look and feel of `<polymer-*>` UI elements and it is tedious to override every style just to get back to baseline. I can post a JSBin if necessary.

Comment: If you could be more specific, that would help. It's a balancing act. Also, suggest you look at the `core-*` elements and use those instead of `polymer-ui-*` moving forward.

Comment: Ah, thank you. `core-*` seems useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To override an element's styles from the outside, you can use `::shadow` and `/deep/`:
http://www.polymer-project.org/articles/styling-elements.html#style-fromoutside

Those pierce through the Shadow DOM boundaries and allow you to target nodes internal to the element.  Unfortunately, this means you need to explicitly write rules that target these nodes. This is sort of the deal with components...an author defines the look and feel, but you're welcome to override it as consumer/developer.

It's also worth noting that the visual elements use the non-visual `core-*`/`polymer-*` elements to get their job done. If you need a completely different UI, I'd create an element that reuses those core elements.